# element-wise matrix multiplication after imread

Tags: matlab, matrix

I can't calculate the product of `eye(100)` and `s = imread('1','gif')`. The dimensions of the matrices are equal, but MATLAB notes the following error:

> `Error using .*
>
>   Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar
>   doubles.`

How can I define `s` as a matrix with float values in MATLAB?

Comment: why would you multiply by eye anyway. It is going to return the same thing?

Comment: It will only keep the diagonal, everything else will be black.

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB's `imread` returns a matrix with elements of type `uint8` (unsigned 8-bit integers). In contrast with `eye(100)`, which produces a matrix of type `double`. Since the operation `.*`  is not defined for operands of different types, you need to convert `s` to `double` before manipulating it:

```
s = double(imread('1', 'gif'));
```

Comment: Eitan, this maybe isn't as clear as many of your other answers. It's not quite true that `imread` returns `uint8`s, it's that the image is `uint8`. And it's not quite true that `.*` is not defined for `uint8`, it's that you can't apply it to two arguments of different class. Maybe a little edit?

Comment: @SamRoberts [The documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html#f25-722074) says  that `imread` for an input GIF image returns `uint8` (unless it is a 1-bit image). I'm not sure about the `.*` part, but I'll take your word for it.

Comment: Er, what? When you say "imread for an input GIF image returns uint8 (unless it is a 1-bit image)", are you agreeing with me that "It's not quite true that imread returns uint8s, it's that the image is uint8"? Your sentence seems to imply mine (for gifs), rather than rebutting it.

Comment: @SamRoberts If you're referring to "the image" as the input file, then  no. The input file is not a `uint8` matrix, it's a sequence of binary data. If you're talking about the matrix that `imread` returns, then yes, we're saying the same thing then.